# How to update an image on a Canvas?

Tags: python, tkinter

This is the essence of the code I'm having trouble with:

```
camelot = Canvas(main, width = 400, height = 300)
camelot.grid(row = 0, column = 0, rowspan = 11, columnspan = 3)
MyImage = PhotoImage(file = "sample1.gif")
camelot.create_image(0, 0, anchor = NW, image = MyImage)
```

This is run at the beginning. What I want to do on later in another function is replace `"sample1.gif"` by `"sample2.gif"`, and, possibly later on, replace that in turn by `"sample3.gif"`.  I'm stuck and nothing I've been trying has worked so far.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Adding image to canvas:

```
self.image_on_canvas = self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, image = ...)
```

Changing image on canvas:

```
self.canvas.itemconfig(self.image_on_canvas, image = ...)
```

---

Full example:

```
from Tkinter import *

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

class MainWindow():

    #----------------
    
    def __init__(self, main):
        
        # canvas for image
        self.canvas = Canvas(main, width=60, height=60)
        self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)
        
        # images
        self.my_images = []
        self.my_images.append(PhotoImage(file="ball1.gif"))
        self.my_images.append(PhotoImage(file="ball2.gif"))
        self.my_images.append(PhotoImage(file="ball3.gif"))
        self.my_image_number = 0
        
        # set first image on canvas
        self.image_on_canvas = self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor='nw', image=self.my_images[self.my_image_number])
        
        # button to change image
        self.button = Button(main, text="Change", command=self.onButton)
        self.button.grid(row=1, column=0)
        
    #----------------

    def onButton(self):
        
        # next image
        self.my_image_number += 1

        # return to first image
        if self.my_image_number == len(self.my_images):
            self.my_image_number = 0

        # change image
        self.canvas.itemconfig(self.image_on_canvas, image=self.my_images[self.my_image_number])

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

root = Tk()
MainWindow(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Images used in example:

ball1.gif [image: ball1.gif] ball2.gif [image: ball2.gif] ball3.gif [image: ball3.gif]

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
    MyImage = PhotoImage(file = "sample1.gif")
    labelorbuttontodisplayit.image = MyImage
    labelorbuttontodisplayit.configure(image=MyImage)
```

:P that should do it. I only tried to use that code on label or buttons, never as a Canvas, but i guess you can adapt that piece of code a bit.