# how to change a image in tinker pressing a button

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making an intro sequence that displays an image with text underneath. the image is supposed to change when the button 'next' is pressed. When I press the button it gives me this error:

```
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Isaac\Desktop\code\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1470, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Isaac\Desktop\code\Programs\Newlife (concept)\Newlife.py", line 15, in next
    pic1=PhotoImage(file=img)
  File "C:\Users\Isaac\Desktop\code\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 3306, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\Isaac\Desktop\code\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 3262, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
TclError: couldn't open "pic3.gif": no such file or directory
```

Note; this happens after i press the button 3 times. I only want to have to press it once.

my code:

```
    from Tkinter import *

Intro= [
    "In the year 2164 Humanity killed itself.",
    ]
pic=0

def next():
    global pic
    pic+=1
    img='pic'+str(pic)+'.gif'
    pic1=PhotoImage(file=img)
    image.create_image(0,0,image=pic1,anchor=NW)

intro_scene = Tk()
intro_scene.title('Destoyed')


text=Label(intro_scene,text=Intro[0],height=2)
image=Canvas(width=300,height=200)

Continue=Button(intro_scene,text='continue',bg='green',bd=3,width=10,command=next)
back=Button(intro_scene,text='back',bg='red',bd=3,width=5)

pic1=PhotoImage(file='pic1.gif')
image.create_image(0,0,image=pic1,anchor=NW)

image.pack(side='top'),text.pack(),back.pack(side='left'),Continue.pack(side='right')
intro_scene.mainloop()
```

I have checked that the whole `next()` function is run like so:

```
def next():
    global pic
    print 'okay1'
    pic+=1
    print 'okay2'
    img='pic'+str(pic)+'.gif'
    print 'okay3'
    pic1=PhotoImage(file=img)
    print 'okay4'
    image.create_image(0,0,image=pic1,anchor=NW)
    print 'okay5'
```

Everything is printed.

My images are in GIF format and are named pic1, pic2, pic3, ect. The first image opens fine on startup.

Comment: Are you sure that pic3.gif is in your current directory. I have tried your code and I don't get any errors.

Comment: I also recommend looking here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19838972/python-tkinter-update-image-in-canvas

Comment: Do you understand what the error message is telling you? It's telling you exactly what the problem is.

Comment: i want it to open pic2.gif not pic3.gif. if i change the name of pic2.gif to pic3.gif it says that pic2.gif is not found.