# why capture video does not refresh in tkinter loop?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am expecting video capture refreshes the screen. When it was not a class it was working as I expected. Then I converted it to oop -below.
It did not refresh... Then I expected "after" would do the work. Apperently I did not understand how after works? Does not it call -in my case below- root.vidImg.vid() continuously. If yes why self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) does not captures and shows a new image?
Thanks for the helps in advance

here is my code...

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import cv2



class Window(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        self.videoFrm = tk.Frame(self, width=480, bg='yellow', height=320)
        self.videoFrm.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.NW)
        self.vidImg = cnvs(self.videoFrm,self)
        self.vidImg.grid()

class cnvs(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.controller = controller

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=480, height=320, bg='green')
        self.canvas.grid()

    def vid(self):
        # Capture video frames
        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

        _, self.frame = self.cap.read()
        self.img = cv2.flip(self.frame, 1)

        self.cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(self.img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
        self.cv2image = cv2.resize(self.cv2image, (0, 0), fx=0.2, fy=0.2)
        self.img = Image.fromarray(self.cv2image)
        self.imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=self.img)

        self.canvas.create_image(10, 10, anchor=tk.NW, image=self.imgtk)

def main():

    root = Window()
    root.after(0, root.vidImg.vid())
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create an [animation loop with the `after` method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2401181/4084269), you need to let the animation function call itself multiple times.

In your case, you could add the following method to the `cnvs` class:

```
def video_loop(self):
    self.vid()
    self.controller.after(10, self.video_loop)
```

and then call it just before the `mainloop()`.

Furthermore, instead of adding a new image to the canvas for each frame, it's probably better to just [change the existing image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19842646/4084269) using `canvas.itemconfig(...)`.

Comment: thank you for the both pieces of advice; worked well

Comment: @Ekmel, you're welcome! Please [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/361431) to show that your issue is resolved ;)