# Drawing Image in tkinter canvas fails

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make tkinter UI that changes the image by control: loading folder/file, initiate, etc.

My code is at below and it does not load any image.

```
window = tk.Tk()

class window_tk():
    def __init__(self,main):
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(main, bg='white' )
        self.init_img_route = "C:/Users/ISDL_gram/Documents/hpe/3.png"
        self.img = itk.PhotoImage(file=self.init_img_route)
        self.bg= self.canvas.create_image(0,0,anchor = tk.NW,image=self.img)
        width = self.img.width()
        height = self.img.height()
        main.geometry(str(width+100)+'x'+str(height+100))
        self.canvas.pack(fill='both',expand=1)


window_tk(window)
window.mainloop()
```

Since I succeeded loading img when I made my code function-based, and I referred [How to update an image on a Canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19838972/how-to-update-an-image-on-a-canvas/19842646) and decided to make it using class, which does not work. What did I miss? I have no clue.

---

I editted the code slightly, only showing codes for images.

Comment: Do you have several `tk.Tk` instances?

Comment: Any error shown in the console / terminal?  If yes, post the traceback.

Comment: How do you create the instance of `window_tk`?

Comment: I don't get the image if I do `window_tk(window)` but I get it if I do `w = window_tk(window)` so this seems to be a problem of garbage collection.

Comment: @j_4321  I editted the code slightly. Since the full code is long for here I only wrote things related to image.

Comment: @EJSong Do you see the image if you replace `window_tk(window)` by `w = window_tk(window)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you did not use a variable to store the reference of `window_tk` class, so it is garbage collected.  Save a reference:

```
window = tk.Tk()

class window_tk():
    def __init__(self,main):
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(main, bg='white' )
        self.init_img_route = "C:/Users/ISDL_gram/Documents/hpe/3.png"
        self.img = itk.PhotoImage(file=self.init_img_route)
        self.bg= self.canvas.create_image(0,0,anchor = tk.NW,image=self.img)
        width = self.img.width()
        height = self.img.height()
        main.geometry(str(width+100)+'x'+str(height+100))
        self.canvas.pack(fill='both',expand=1)


app = window_tk(window) # save a reference
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Wow. You genius.